# App showing typical police traps location

Tags: android, ios, gps, finance, car

I am looking for an iOS or Android application that can show police traps (for speed radar) located closed to me. I currently use [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze&hl=en) but it only shows current police traps. To increase my safety, I would like to see some history of police trap locations, e.g. over the last X days/weeks/months. Any price is good. I am mostly interested in the US, specifically California and Massachusetts.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this also applies to the US, but as far as I know, devices to detect speed radars are illegal. So are those apps. But I'm pretty sure every country handles this individually.

Comment: @alex waze is legal in the us, it simply relies on people reporting police.

Comment: Like I said, maybe it doesn't apply to the US. But here *also that* is illegal. There was a big controversy about people reporting police traps on Facebook or on other social media networks. I don't like it. an ex-cop once told me it stopped being about security a long time ago. It's all about the money.

Comment: In California speed traps are mostly a tax. I don't like that.