# Android app to detect police or speed radar presence

Tags: android, car, object-recognition

I am looking for an Android application that can detect police or speed radar presence by using the camera when driving. (i.e. based on object recognition, not database-based like this question looking for an [app showing typical police traps locations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20439/app-showing-typical-police-traps-location))

Any price is good. If location specific (since cop colors and equipment change from place to place), I am mostly interested in the US, specifically California and Massachusetts.

---

Same question for iOS: [iOS app to detect police or speed radar presence](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35846/903)

Comment: Presumably you are looking for visual recognition and are not too worried about unmarked police vehicles - _in the UK we have them for traffic as well as more serious crime & the constabularies have been know to swap them between them when they get too well known_.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks, good to know, I wasn't of this issue in the UK. I know cops do the same in California but not so frequent.

Comment: In order for the police car to be big enough in the camera picture for the image-based detection algorithms to work decently you'd likely be already too close to the speed traps to slow down in time :) Plus often the speed trap placements are in zones with limited visual range, further reducing the effectiveness of a camera-based solution.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I agree, but still useful in many cases :) e.g. to avoid inadvertently overtaking a police car when speeding. Also for the longer term, one could foresee Waze-style police reports automatically fed by such applications.

Answer (score 1):

If your police vehicles and speed cameras are clearly marked, *in some countries they are not always*, then you could use the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) android implementation for something like this.

There are a number of resources and guides linked from [this page](http://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-detect-and-track-object-with-opencv/) as object detection, (not necessarily police vehicles), is a common problem in robotics. Beware of the simple colour detection mechanisms as they will tend to give too many false positives, *(due to matching colours in the environment unless the police in your area use **really** unusual colours)*, and false negatives, *(due to changing light conditions)*.